# MLFlow error during `mlflow ui` in terminal

Tags: python, mlflow, mlops

The previous week everything was fine and I did experiment tracking. This week when I ran it, that is, when I wrote `mlflow ui` in the terminal in the same directory where the project was, it started me giving error. Error:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pydantic/deprecated/class_validators.py", line 228, in root_validator
    raise PydanticUserError(
pydantic.errors.PydanticUserError: If you use `@root_validator` with pre=False (the default) you MUST specify `skip_on_failure=True`. Note that `@root_validator` is deprecated and should be replaced with `@model_validator`
```

I uninstalled mlflow and re-installed, but still, the issue is there.

Answer (score 0):

You have to downgrade to `mlfow@2.5.0`, maybe it helps.
I had the same issue with just running `mlflow` on version 2.6.0. Found this quiet fresh thread:
https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/issues/9331

Unfortunately, my mlflow is now running but not the UI, same error as you described. But 2.4.0 also did not work, so maybe it is a specific problem within my project.